# Dynamically create combox and reset values TKinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I generate dynamically combo box and place all the values inside the combox box using
list values.
When I clicked , clearall button, I want to set all the combox box values to "None"
I tried lot of ways. But it shows error message "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'"
below is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb 
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import tkinter as tk 


root = Tk()
root.title("my application")
sizex = 500
sizey = 500
posx  = 50
posy  = 50
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

value1=['country1','country2','country3','country4','country5',"None"]
comblist =['combo_box1','combo_box2','combo_box3','combo_box4']

y2=80
for comb in comblist:        
    comb= ttk. Combobox(root, values=value1, state="readonly")
    comb.set("country1")
    comb.place(x=200,y=y2)

    y2=y2+30
    
def clearvalues(): 
    res = mb.askquestion('ClearValues',  "Want to clear all the setting ?")
    if res == 'yes' :         
        for cmb1 in comblist:   
             cmb1.set("None")
    else : 
        mb.showinfo('Return', 'Cancelled')                   

Button_clearall = Button(root,text="CLEARALL",command = clearvalues)
Button_clearall.place(x=100, y=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `comblist` to a list of strings. If you want to iterate over comboboxes you need to iterate over the comboboxes, not strings.

There are many ways to do this. In your specific case it's probably easiest to just get rid of the original definition of `comblist` and replace it with a list of comboxes.

```
comblist = []
for i in range(4):        
    comb= ttk. Combobox(root, values=value1, state="readonly")
    comblist.append(comb)
    ...
```

With that, your code to iterate over `comblist` will work:

```
 for cmb1 in comblist:   
     cmb1.set("None")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function `clearvalues():` You are iterating through the `comblist` variable and not the actual Combobox's that you have created. That's why  `"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'"` is being returned. You are iterating through a string inside of the lists.

Creating Combobox's through iteration is not advised as accessing them later on is difficult. I would recommend creating 5 individual ComboBox's and going from there.

Edit: Just to make this a little clearer for you. If you change the function `clearvalues():` to look like this:

```
def clearvalues():
    res = mb.askquestion('ClearValues', "Want to clear all the setting ?")
    if res == 'yes':
        for cmb1 in comblist:
            print(type(cmb1))
    else:
        mb.showinfo('Return', 'Cancelled')
```

Now run the program and click yes to clear all settings. You will see in your terminal that the `cmb1` type is a string and not a ComboBox

Comment: _"Creating Combobox's through iteration is not advised as accessing them later on is difficult. "_ - that is simply not true. Accessing them later is trivial by saving them to a list or dictionary.

Comment: Just because something can be done doesn't mean it should be done.

Comment: Very true, but creating widgets in a loop is not one of those things. It's a very common technique to reduce duplicate code when you need many nearly identical widgets.

Comment: Please help me in my above code,how it should be written using for loop

Comment: @Continuit You should always try to follow DRY - Dont Repeat Yourself concept to make code more efficient, looping here is the best way, and it is also not that difficult to understand too.